# Two distinct lines for which there is no plane that contains both

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

So if a plane contains a line, does that mean every point of that line is a point on the plane? And if so, would lines that are skewed and perpendicular be an example of the statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So if a plane contains a line, does that mean every point of that line is a point on the plane?

Yes, that is by definition.

> Would lines that are skewed and perpendicular be an example of the statement?

Sure. Any pair of lines on a plane will either be parallel or they'll intersect (just like in $\Bbb R^2$). So, any pair of skew lines will work.